# Changing the hostname on a Business Objects XI 3.1 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sap

What steps do i need to use to change the hostname of a Business Objects XI 3.1 server?

The name of the windows server 2008 core host has changed, and all the administrative web applications are trying to post requests to the old name of the server. Is there any way to update these to point to the new server name? Or alternatively do i just set up the hosts file so the new hostname is aliased to the localhost loop back address?

And are there any other steps i need to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried several times to do this. In the end decided it was best to export the repository, uninstall business objects and reinstall.

The hostname is hardcoded in too many places to make this an easy task.

Comment: Excellent answer, you were down voted for some odd reason. Have a great day!